# View TFS commit history offline

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops, commit

Can I view TFS commit history in Visual Studio (>2013) in offline mode or view latest changes that committed by me? 

our TFS server now not available and we switched to new server by creating new TFS project and copy  old project to this. Is there any way to view local  project history?

**edit** 
We used TFS without git.

Comment: Are you using git repository with TFVC or just plain old TFS repository?

Comment: Is there anyfeedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Like Daniel mentioned that if you are using **Git** version control, you could view latest changes of your local repository when you are offline.

  In Team Explorer, click Home-->Branches-->select a branch-->right click choosing **View History**.
  It provides all commits for this branches with the Author information, double click to view the detail changes for each commit.
- If you're using **TFVC**, you can't achieve that when you're offline.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Git, absolutely. Git stores all revision history in the repo, so cloning the repo brings revision history automatically.

If you're using TFVC, no. TFVC history is stored on the server and requires the server to be available in order to see history.